# Yii2 вопрос по валидации

Tags: php, yii2, валидация

Делаю валидацию в Yii2 и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Задаю правило `['categoryIDs','each','rule' => ['required']]`, в котором указываю, что поле должно быть обязательно заполнено(`'categoryIDs'` - это массив в котором содержатся атрибуты полей ввода формы, например, для `$form->field($model, 'name')`, это будет `'name'`).

Сама проблема. Ввожу данные в поля ввода. Оставляю (одно или более) поле ввода пустым (кликаю мышкой в поле, а потом за пределами поля), а в низу под полем не появляется сообщение о том, что это поле должно быть заполнено.

Если же использовать конструкцию `[['name','password'], 'required']` - то сообщение об обязательности заполнения поля появляется.

Answer (score 1):

Отдельно нужно перечислять какие поля обязательны для заполнения и отдельно проверять тип данных.
Должно быть где-то так:

```
[['categoryIDs'], 'required'], //сюда можно дописать другие обязательные поля
['categoryIDs', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-eachvalidator.html

Так же учитываем, что данный валидатор доступен с версии 2.0.4. Нужно убедиться, что версия фреймворка соответствует или выше.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет желания настраивать правила в rules(), создай кастомную функцию валидации. Например:

```
public function rules() {
    return [['categoryIDs', 'customValidateFunction']];
}

public function customValidateFunction($attribute, $params)
{
    $paramsForValidate = ['name', 'password'];

    foreach($paramsForValidate as $paramName) {
        if (empty($this->$paramName)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Error message');
        }
    }
}
```

Понятно, что это бред, чисто для примера. Но в целом показывает, как можно настроить правила валидации более тонко (хотя и стандартного функционала вполне должно хватить)

Answer (score -1):

`each` не выполняется на стороне клиента и не работает с `required`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?